# Static member of non-template class with template method

Tags: templates, static-members

I have the following class structure:

```
class A {
  template<typename T> static void f(const T& input) {
     //do something with X and input
  }
  static ostringstream x;
}
```

Then in main I do:

```
...
int n = 5;
A::f(n);
...
```

This compiles fine, but I get a linkage error that A::x is a symbol that cannot be found. Has anyone encountered this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you've yet to define `x`:

```
// A.cpp
std::ostringstream A::x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `A::f<int>(n);`  instead.